# Why do I get the same value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const allLi = document.querySelectorAll('li');
        for (let i = 0; i < allLi.length; i++) {
            console.log(allLi[i].offsetLeft)
            allLi[i].style.position = 'absolute'
        }
```

```css
    body,
    ul {
        margin: 0;
    }

    ul {
        width: 600px;
        padding-left: 0;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 100px auto 0;
    }

    li {
        width: 100px;
        height: 120px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
        user-select: none;
    }
```

```html
 <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
</ul>
```

It is possible to get the offsetLeft of each element without the following location code?

I do not understand, the positioning is executed in the following. The execution should be able to obtain the position before positioning?

Comment: offsetLeft gets the left position with respect to the parent for any block element. Top offset will change for each element in a list, but left offset won't change. Am I missing something?

Comment: answer to your question `Why do I get the same value?`: because all `li` have the same left position.

Comment: What is the end result that you are trying to achieve ?